# Can TeX/LaTeX draw lines at precise positions?

Tags: positioning, rules, plain-tex

I need to draw lines at specific distances (in mm).
For example:

```
---- line 0
---- line 1 at 35.64 mm below line 0
---- line 2 at 33.64 mm below line 1
```

The macro I'm using is as follows (I don't remember from where I copied it):

```
\def\fr#1{
  \vbox{  
    \dimen0=#1
    %\advance \dimen0 by -2.41pt
    \advance \dimen0 by -1pt
    \vskip \dimen0
    \vrule height 0.5pt depth 0.5pt width 2in
  }
}
```

And I use it as follows:

```
\parindent=0pt
\baselineskip=-\maxdimen
\lineskiplimit=\maxdimen
\lineskip=0pt


\#0 \fr{1mm}
\#1 \fr{35.64}
\#2 \fr{33.64}
```

However I cannot get the lines to appear at the desired positions.

Answer (score 6):

This should be a matter of `\vrule` and `\vskip` only. The following should work:

```
\def\fr#1#2{\vskip #2\noindent\smash{#1}%
  \vrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width 2in\relax}

\fr{0}{0mm}
\fr{1}{35.64mm}
\fr{2}{33.64mm}

\bye
```

Note how the `\smash` macro is used to prevent the numbers from adding any height or depth.

Comment: Is the AMS `\smash` very different in use/behaviour from plain `\smash`?

Comment: @morbusg: No, it's just that I didn't know Plain TeX also has it.

Comment: i may be missing something, but doesn't the rule height accumulate?  it's not smashed ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton: It does, and it's what I intended. The question asks for relative line position, not absolute. egreg has the other alternative, so let the op choose the correct one.

Answer (score 5):

A Plain solution (inspired by Andrey's one):

```
\def\fr#1#2{\vskip #2\smash{#1 \vrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width 2in}}

\offinterlineskip

% A ruler in the margin to show alignment
\llap{\smash{\vtop to 100pt{
  \leaders\vbox to 20pt{\leaders\vrule\vfill\hrule width 2mm}\vfill}}}

\fr{0}{20pt}
\fr{y}{40pt}
\fr{2}{20pt}

\bye
```

[image]